# too many emails getting triggered from google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to trigger an email each time a row is updated on a google sheet. However too many emails are getting triggered when 1 row is being added. The Code I am using is below.

`

```
function valueCheck(e) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1= ss.getSheetByName("Applications");
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var companyName = 2;
  var applicationLink=3;
  var com = sheet1.getRange(lastRow, companyName).getValue();
  var link1= sheet1.getRange(lastRow, applicationLink).getValue();
  if (link1)
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail("r***@gmail.com","Apply to "+com,"link to apply:"+link1);
}
}
```

Comment: What trigger are you using?

Comment: Assuming  that you're using an onEdit() or onChange() you're are not limiting it to just one sheet so any edits or changes done on the spreadsheet could potentially fire the trigger.

Comment: I am using onChange(), how would I limit it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  const sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
  //e.source.toast('Entry');//for debugging
  //sh.getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));//You use this to learn more about the event object
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.changeType=="EDIT") {//I assume you're using EDIT changeType
    //e.source.toast('Sheet1')//for debugging
    //do your stuff in here
  }
}
```

I don't know what changeType you want to use.